# Drupal Commerce Kickstart - allow anonymous users to see disabled products

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-commerce

I have a very simple implementation of Drupal Commerce Kickstart on http://casacinepoa.com.br/loja. I do not use the stock modules and I am not planning in use those, as the stock is handled by the customer's ERP (they also sell their products in their real store, using the existing stock management).

What I want to do, however, is to change the "add to cart" button to "product not available" when the product is disabled and still show the product on display and searches, so people will know they exist. I noticed this works the way as expected if I access the product page directly: http://www.casacinepoa.com.br/loja/pt-br/productdisplay/decamer%C3%A3o-com%C3%A9dia-do-sexo - there you will see the Product not Available. However, the product will not show under its category (http://www.casacinepoa.com.br/loja/pt-br/product_category/5) or in the search results if I search for its name.

Anonymous users already have the permission to see all products.

I have been searching all over and I could not find a way to do this.

All help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a new view that has disable and enabled products in its filters with products as its relationship.